# Rename "cn" in LDAP (linux)

Tags: unix, ldap, administration

I want to rename the "cn" attribute on a user entry in a LDAP. I've tried the smbldap_tools to modify this attribute with the `-N` switch but that does not work that way.

Is there another commandline tool or switch to change the "cn" attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cn` is one of the RDNs in the distinguished name, then it can be changed by the `ModifyDN` request. Otherwise, `cn` can be changed with a modify request. See the article ["LDAP: Renaming ..."](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/mastering-moddn/) for renaming a distinguished name, and ["LDAP: Multi-valued attributes ..."](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/replace-a-value-of-a-multi-valued-attribute/) if `cn` is not an RDN component of the distinguished name.

Comment: Thanks. `ldapmodify` is a great tool!